# Delete X files in each folders and sub folders

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to delete files in a folder and its subfolders but not `X` last files again in each folder. For example in `C:\Test` I want to keep 10 txt files but also in `C:\Test\subtest1` and `C:\Test\subtest2`. Here, `X` X is the number of files I want to keep.

But it will not keep 10 files in each folder but in the entire arborescence.

My script is not fully functional, but it did it well in the `C:\Test` directory:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted $txtfiles = 'C:\Users\MUC8VX\Documents\Test
ForEach-Object {    Get-ChildItem $txtfiles | where{ -not $_.PsIsContainer}|
     sort LastWriteTime -desc| select -Skip 10 |
     Remove-Item -Include *.txt* -Force }
```

And if I add `-Recurse` it will not keep 10 files in each folders but in the entire arborescence:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$txtfiles =`C:\Users\MUC8VX\Documents\Test'
ForEach-Object {    Get-ChildItem $txtfiles -Recurse | where{ -not
 $_.PsIsContainer}| sort LastWriteTime -desc|
     select -Skip 10 | Remove-Item -Include *.txt* -Force }
```

edit :
Thanks a lot Manuel Batsching.

Here's a generic script :

```
#Insert your parent folder which contains files and subfolders

Get-Childitem -Path C:\Your\Parent\Folder -Recurse | 

Group-Object Directory | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group |

        #sort by the last written files 
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |

        #Keep the X last files you want to keep 
        Select-Object -Skip X |

        #Remove files according to their extension
        Remove-Item -Include *.extension* -Force }
```

Comment: Do you have only one level of subfolders? Or will there be paths like `C:\Test\subtest1\subsubtest1` ?

Comment: I have C:\Test ; C:\Test\subtest1 ; C:\Test\subtest2

Comment: so for now only one level. But it will more interresting if it can work with X levels

Comment: I feel you probably already have considered this, but is will be needful to ensure the sorting rules for the files in those directories will always be such that an algo to leave just the bottom/last *x* number... will leave the files intended?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean... But my "sorting rule" is define by "sort LastWriteTime -desc" and the "-Skip X" to leave the X last written files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution, that also applies to nested subfolders, you can list all files recursively and then group them by the path of their respective parent folder. Then apply your sorting rules and reduce each group to 10 elements.

```
Get-Childitem *.txt -Recurse | 
    Group-Object Directory | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Group | 
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
            Select-Object -Skip 10 | 
            Remove-Item }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested but you can try this.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$txtfiles = 'C:\Users\MUC8VX\Documents\Test'
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path $txtfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.fullname -Include *.txt | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 10 | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Basically, this code iterate over each folder recursively, for each folder, it find the files, skip 10 and remove all others.